# How to upgrade from Ubuntu to Ubuntu Netbook Edition?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

Currently for testing purposes I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 Lycid Lynx on my laptop. Is there any way I can upgrade to Ubuntu Netbook Edition without reinstalling the OS itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo aptitude install ubuntu-netbook` should do this for you quite cleanly. I recommend taking a backup of any important data before you start though, just in case, as many packages are added and configured and some will be removed or reconfigured.

For Ubuntu versions older than Lucid, the command would instead be `sudo aptitude install ubuntu-netbook-remix`